# Можно ли сделать ввод кода авторизации в winform для Vk.net?

Tags: c#, vknet

Работаю с Vk.net. Пробую сделать 2 факторную авторизацию.Согласно документации на место 5 параметра надо передать в текстовом формате переменную. 
Здесь пример для консоли.
В документации:

```
var api = new VkApi();

api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
{
    ApplicationId = 123456,
    Login = "Login",
    Password = "Password",
    Settings = Settings.All,
    TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Code:");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
});
```

Проект у меня winform.
Хочу сделать вызов формы, чтобы ввести код. Но у меня не получается это реализовать.
Пробовал так:

```
Form3 form = new Form3(); 
form.Show();
```

Так же пробовал сюда вызывать метод,

```
private void Hello()
    {
        Form3 form = new Form3();
        form.Show();

    }


внутри авторизации вызывал так:
TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
            {

                Hello();
                return DataBank.Text;




            }
```

выбивает ошибку:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "Эта операция не поддерживается для относительных URI-адресов."
```

Comment: А что такое DataBank.Text?

Comment: Создал класс статичных переменных, для обмена нужными данными между формами, здесь пока использовал DataBank.Text , в него строковое значение пишу, планировал вызов 3 формы делать и в него код подтверждения записывать.

Comment: Помогли решить проблему :
на место 5 параметра где консоль вызов
TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
{
      //Console.WriteLine("Enter Code:");
      //return Console.ReadLine();
 
      var frm = new EnterCodeForm();
      frm.ShowDialog();
      return frm.Code;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли решить.В месте 5 параметра

```
TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
{
  //Console.WriteLine("Enter Code:");
  //return Console.ReadLine();

  var frm = new EnterCodeForm();
  frm.ShowDialog();
  return frm.Code;
}
```

Код формы

```
public partial class EnterCodeForm: Form
 {
 // tbCodeTextBox - компонент типа TextBox, размещенный на диалоговой форме EnterCodeForm
 public EnterCodeForm()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
 }   

 public string Code { get { return  tbCodeTextBox.Text; }}
 }
```